# Separating chaining method call

Tags: java, javafx

Is it possible separating methods on their call? So we don't call those methods in line? I mean like a snippet below :

```
//configure path transition and run it
 PathTransition pathTransition = PathTransitionBuilder.create()
            .duration(Duration.seconds(6))
            .path(path)
            .node(rect)
            .orientation(OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT)
            .cycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE)
            .autoReverse(false)
            .build();
    pathTransition.play();
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with javafx, but this is classic example of builder pattern. you are calling each method to override default settings for constructor, so yes it is possible

Comment: @user902383, so we call it "builder pattern" ?? ,is it possible to separate those methods ? when i learnt NIO there somewhat same examples, but in javafx , it's just too complex ..

Comment: Each of these methods return the same type (here `PathTransitionBuilder`) so you can apply them in a chain and also interchangeably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is each of those methods is actually returning the object the method is in, which allows another method call to then be made.

```
PathTransition pathTransition = PathTransitionBuilder.create()
        .duration(Duration.seconds(6))
        .path(path)
        .node(rect)
        .orientation(OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT)
        .cycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE)
        .autoReverse(false)
        .build();
```

Is the same as:

```
PathTransitionBuilder pathTransitionBuilder = PathTransitionBuilder.create();
pathTransitionBuilder .duration(Duration.seconds(6));
pathTransitionBuilder .path(path);
pathTransitionBuilder .node(rect);
pathTransitionBuilder .orientation(OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);
pathTransitionBuilder .cycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
pathTransitionBuilder .autoReverse(false);
PathTransition pathTransition = pathTransitionBuilder.build();
```

Comment: thanks, works great ! btw there's a typo above, PathTransition  pathTransition = pathTransition.build(); should be PathTransition   pathTransition = pathTransitionBuilder.build();

Comment: Note that these builders have been deprecated in JavaFX8, and probably should not be used.

Comment: @james : serously ? i had just came to Animation section and it's already deprecated ?? , lol..

Comment: [All JavaFX builders are deprecated:](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2013-March/006725.html) they were implemented incorrectly. The Animations themselves are not deprecated, just that way of creating them. Just instantiate `PathTransition` and call `set` methods in the usual way.